# Which NodeJS encryption method should I use to secure information?

Tags: node.js, cryptography

It seems like there are three way to encrypt a password using the crypto module in NodeJS. When should each be used?

1. `crypto.createCipheriv(algorithm, key, iv)`
2. `crypto.pbkdf2Sync(password, salt, 100000, 512, 'sha256')`
3. `crypto.createHash('sha256').update('some data').digest('base64')`

From what I can tell, (1) has a Decipher counterpart to decrypt the password. To verify a password using (2) & (3), you have to run the same fn with the same args and check if result is the same as the hashed password.

Comment: Notes you generally don't *encrypt* passwords, you *hash* them. It's strictly a one-way process.

Comment: See https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/211/how-to-securely-hash-passwords?noredirect=1&lq=1 for why it's considered best practice to salt and hash passwords.